# Use Foursquare API to post updates to a venue

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm not really sure if I'm missing anything on the 4square API...

I am currently trying to post an update for a venue.

The user token is the user that manages this venue (with whom I can post updates via the Foursquare website)

The venues are not using Business Pages.

Is there any other way to post updates that with pages?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [pageupdates/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pageupdates/add) endpoint. The venue must be associated with a page in order to post page updates.